# How to do if something happened make number - 1

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, if-statement, c#-2.0

I am trying to do when i destroy all boxes something happen.
My code is;

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


public class destroy : MonoBehaviour
{

private string BALL_TAG = "ball";
public AudioClip coin;
public AudioSource src;
public float numBox = 120f;
public bool isDestroyed;




private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag(BALL_TAG))
    {
        src.clip = coin;
        src.Play();
        Destroy(gameObject);
        isDestroyed = true;

    }
}

private void Update()
{
    boxes();
}

public void boxes()
{
    if(isDestroyed == true)
        numBox -= 1f;

    if(numBox == 119)
        SceneManager.LoadScene("mainManu");
}

private IEnumerator Two()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

}

But it doesn't work.
It is suppose to do when I broke 1 box it sends me to menu.
I think its problem in "numBox -= 1f;" because I don't know hot to make this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your code completely. So, I need to make some assumptions.
I think the Script is attached to the box and every box has this Script. I also think, that  your player Shoots Ball. Those Balls have a collider with an ball tag.

There are multiple problems with your code.

The first one is, that your count variable, numBox, is saved in your destroy Script, which is placed on each box.
this means, that every Box is counting for itself.

You have to centralize this. There are multiple ways for doing this.
One way is to declare this variable as static(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static)
This is not best practice, but works.

A Better way is to have a Script on Your Player, which holds this number and every Box searches for this Script and change this number if it is destroyed.

The second big Problem is, that your are doing some really weird thing in your Update and the collision handling

First of all, you are setting `isDestroyed` to true. Then in your boxes method, which is called in every Frame, you are decrementing your `numBox` variable by one, if this is Destroyed is true.

So if your Box gets hit, you are decrementing every frame.

After that you are checking every frame if your numBox is 119
If so, you change the Scene.

This is the reason, why you are getting to your MainMenu after only one boy

This behaviour is very weird, because it is totally unnecessary. You can reduce your variable directly in in your OnCollisionEnter2D Method.

There are some little things, which can be improved.

1. When you are trying to play a Sound, you don't have to specify the AudioClip in code. You can assign this directly in Unity on the AudioSource Component via drag and drop. This makes your code simpler.
2. You are not calling the Two Coroutine. You've specified this Coroutine but don't call it.

````
    //Script on Player
    public class PlayerBoxDestroyManager:MonoBehaviour
    {
        public int StartBoxes = 120;
        private int Boxes;
    
        private void Start()
        {
            Boxes = StartBoxes;
        }
    
        public void DestroyBox()
        {
            //Reduce our Boxes count
            //This is equal to Boxes -= 1 
            //                 Boxes = Boxes -1
            Boxes--;
    
            // If we have less or zero Boxes left, we End call our EndGame methode
            if(Boxes <= 0)
            {
                EndGame();
            }
        }
    
        private void EndGame()
        {
            // We change the Scene to the mainMenu
            SceneManager.LoadScene("mainManu");
        }
    }
    ```
````

```
//Script on all Boxes
public class Box : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string Balltag = "ball";

    //Audio Source the Audio Clip has to be assigned in the Unity editor
    public AudioSource Coin;

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        //Check it colliding Object has the right Tag
        if(collision.transform.tag == Balltag)
        {
            //Get the reference to the Player Script
            PlayerBoxDestroyManager PBDM = FindObjectOfType<PlayerBoxDestroyManager>();
            //We can now access the Destroy Box Methode
            PBDM.DestroyBox();

            //Play the sound
            Coin.Play();

            //If we destroy our Object now, the Sound would also be deletet. 
            //We want to hear the sound, so we have to wait, till the sound is finished.
            StartCoroutine(WaitTillAudioIsFinished());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator WaitTillAudioIsFinished()
    {
        //we wait till the sound is finished
        while (Coin.isPlaying)
        {
            yield return null;
        }
        //if finished, we destroy the Gameobject
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

```
I hope I helped you. If you have questions, feel free to ask. 
And sorry for my English:)
```